# Laravel stack with custom channel not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm running Laravel 6 and I'm trying to log into default stack file and new relic log.

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 5,
    ],
    'newrelic' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via' => NewRelicLogger::class,
    ]
]
```

Both env `LOG_CHANNEL=stack` and `LOG_CHANNEL=newrelic` are work normally.

When I update the stack's channels to `'channels' => ['daily', 'newrelic']` and env use `LOG_CHANNEL=stack`, it only logs to the file and my custom channel "newrelic" doesn't log anything.

Comment: Could you please share the content of `NewRelicLogger` class?

Comment: https://stevebarbera.medium.com/setting-up-new-relic-logging-in-laravel-7e9dd4834c93  @ThânLƯƠNG Here is the class that I am using

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG   I think I solved this problem, I used ```php artisan cache:clear``` instead of ```php artisan config:cache```. I can work with these channels, thanks for your help.